# C++ Packet-Sniffer using zeroMQ or boost.asio

Tags: c++, boost, network-programming, zeromq, packet-sniffers

I have knowledge in C++ and some kind of knowledge in network-programming...but I have no idea where to start for a Sniffer...My problem is that I made a server and a client.
I am in the same network as the client and the server is far away from us :) . How can I sniff the data which is sent by the client?

I don't care whether to use the boost library or zeroMQ. To make it easier to understand I made this:

```
[SERVER]<-----MESSAGE-----[Router]<-----MESSAGE-----[CLIENT]
                                           |
                                           |
                                           V
                                    [PACKET-SNIFFER]
```

[PACKET-SNIFFER] and [CLIENT] are in the same Network connected by a wi-fi.

Comment: What's wrong with [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)?

Comment: I want to programm it by my own :)

Comment: You can use the API programatically as well. Don't reinvent the wheel please, it's not worth the efforts.

Comment: I don't mean to make a big thing out of that...Just catching the data sent by the client...nothing more

Comment: That's exactly what [WS's libraries](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChapterLibraries.html) provide.

Comment: Well...Thanks I can start with that but i wanted to use the boost library or zeroMQ.

Comment: Note: zeroMQ isn't made, neither suitable for this purpose. It's for building blocks of applications that may use their special sockets to interact.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I sniff the data which is sent by the client?

[Libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org) on UN*X, [WinPcap](http://www.winpcap.org) on Windows.

> [PACKET-SNIFFER] and [CLIENT] are in the same Network connected by a wi-fi.

Then you'll have to capture in [monitor mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode).  Libpcap has APIs to turn on monitor mode, but they currently only work well on OS X; on Linux, you'll probably have to use [aircrack-ng's airmon-ng script](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=airmon-ng) to turn it on, and you might have to do something else on *BSD.  WinPcap doesn't have those APIs, and there's no script equivalent to airmon-ng for Windows.

Comment: What do you think...how did the WhatsApp Sniffer work?

Answer (score 0):

Applications communicate with the network through sockets. Sockets are implemented by operating systems. If you want to sniff what data flows between your client and the network, your best start would be to read up socket documentation of your particular OS and learn what tools does the OS offer to you in this regard. Whatever you do then with the data the OS provided to you is entirely up to you.